# As long as an Android device does not get rooted, is it safe to assume that the main phone app has not been modified?

Tags: android, appsec, forensics

From a forensics standpoint, is there any technical possibility that WITHOUT rooting the device the potential cybercriminal used a manipulated system phone app to have hidden functionalities like secret messaging, which he had modified via a third party hacker/developer?

There were custom phones which had these kinds of apps, but I'm wondering whether this is doable without making a custom ROM or rooting the device (because then the actor has full control).

Comment: Wat do you mean by a *"modified phone app"*? There are millions of apps.

Comment: What do you mean by *"modified via a third party"*?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the main phone app"*? If you really mean an app, there no such thing as a *"the main phone app"*. None of apps is the main one. Do you mean the operating system? But it is not an app. Please explain what you mean.

Comment: From https://www.howtogeek.com/798736/how-to-change-the-default-phone-app-on-android/: "On Android, you have the choice to swap your phone (dialer) apps with something else from the Play Store."

Comment: Android allows installing apps from unknown sources. OS has no way to know if it's a modded or pirated app or an original. For OS, it is just a software that the user has installed.

Comment: Not modified by 3rd-party, but [the manufacturer itself may as well provide a backdoor and malware-ridden system apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224954/44325).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you, I wasn't aware of that. Thank you community, defalt and Andrew. T. answered my question basically.

Comment: @mentallurg I've edited the question to add clarity, thanks for the remarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you cannot rely on your "rooted" detection. The device could have been rooted, modified, and then all traces of intervention carefully erased.

Also, if the attacker has stolen an OEM certificate, they can "upgrade" any system app, injecting malware, without rooting and without manufacturer consent.

And, finally, as @Andrew-t explained, there may be backdoors in specific OEM version of the system, exploited by the attacker.

Answer (score 2):

Yes if there is a vulnerability in the version of Android you are running, including a 0 day (undiscovered) vulnerability then that vulnerability can be exploited.
You can never say something was not exploited.  You can only say you have no evidence of the exploit.  Sorry that's just how security works...

Comment: Welcome to the community. Sorry, but this has barely have something to do with 0 days in the apps themselve. But the comments answeered my question already and someone is welcome to sum it up in a well written answer though ;-)